# How to apply hotfix for multiple past releases using Github Flow

Tags: git, github-flow

Were using GitHub flow for our opensource project, but I don't understand how to handle hotfixes when there are multiple releases branches containing the bug.

Lets say we have versions `0.0.1`, `0.0.2` released and supported by me and another developer.
Were currently working on a new version `0.0.3` which is in `master`.
`master` is stable but not ready since we have a few more features to implement before we can commit to version `0.0.3`.

Say we found a critical bug on `0.0.1` that applies for `0.0.2` and `0.0.3` (which hasn't been deployed yet) too.

What is the steps to apply hotfix for this kind of scenario ?
Do we branch out of `master` and merge the fix to every release ?
Do we version bump each release (v0.0.1b for example) ?

Thanks !

Comment: "Do we branch out of master and merge the fix to every release ?" Yes, and to any actual branches that will need it, such as master. Note that a release tag is a detached head, so you will presumably need to re-tag in some way (ie make new releases): as you put it, "version bump each release".

Comment: 1. "Yes, and to any actual branches that will need it", you mean branch and fix for every release or branch on master, fix, merge to master and every release ?
2. So I'm not creating a new branch for every hotfix (for example v0.1.0 -> v0.1.1), the fix is a part of the v0.1.0 release and I'm simply tagging where the v0.1.1 starts, correct ?

Thank you so much !

Comment: Merge (probably as a cherry pick) the hot fix commit multiple times. That's what a hot fix is.

Comment: Your second question sounds like maybe you need a better understanding of what a merge is, what a branch is, what a tag is, and maybe what Git is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic plan. Switch to `v0.0.1` detached, make the needed fixes, add and commit. Tag that commit, e.g. `v0.0.1b`. Now, in turn, switch to each of the other release tags and cherry-pick `v0.0.1b` onto it and tag it as well. Finally, switch to `main` and any other existing branches that need this fix and cherry-pick `v0.0.1b` onto each of those as well.

That was the **TL:DR**. Now let's talk about *why* this could be a thing to do, and why it's so obvious when you know what Git is, what a branch is, what a tag is, and what a merge is.

**Git** is a directed acyclic graph consisting entirely of commits. Each commit is a snapshot of the *entire* state of the project at a given moment. Each commit has at least one *parent*, which is what gives the graph its directionality. Git does not contain any diffs or even really any history; the history story is simply a spontaneous traversal of the graph, starting at any given commit and moving to its parent, the parent of that, the parent of that, and so on — the *parent chain*.

A **branch** is nothing but a name for one commit. It does have two rather remarkable properties, though: (1) if you are "on" a branch (i.e. that branch is HEAD) and you make a new commit, the branch name is automatically transferred to that commit; and (2) a commit named by a branch will never die, and neither will its parent, nor its parent, and so on. In other words, branches are what keeps the commits in the repo alive.

A **tag** is similar to a branch but without the first magical property; it's a name for a commit, it keeps that commit alive (along with its parent chain), but it never moves from its commit (unless *you* move it, but you probably wouldn't do that, as the purpose of the tag is mark forever a place in the history).

A **merge** is a commit that Git itself makes. It does this by applying *merge logic* to two commits, the one that is HEAD at the time of the merge and the one that is being merged. This merge logic, simply put, involves calculating the diffs from an earlier parent, the *merge base*, and applying both diffs simultaneously to the HEAD.

Now then! You've got your `v0.0.1` commit, and guess what, it's faulty. So you need a place to create a fix. You are going to have construct a piece of the history tree yourself, in a controlled and meaningful way. How should the new topology look? Well, in the first place, you want to keep `v0.0.1` but you also want a *new* commit which is just like it except that it incorporates what you now know are the needed fixes. So you switch to `v0.0.1`, which is possibly only by asking for a detached head, make the changes, and add-and-commit. You now have an excellent commit, but guess what? If you don't do something to preserve it, that commit will die, because it is not named by a branch or a tag and it has no child — all of the things that would keep a commit alive. So you *tag* it, and now it will live forever. I'll call the tag `v0.0.1b` but it's up to you how you want to handle this naming.

Now let's turn to your next release, `v0.0.2`. You want to make the same changes against *it* as well. That's merge logic! In particular, you probably want to `cherry-pick` the commit that you have just created and tagged, the hot fix commit. Why? Well, the merge base used during a cherry-pick is the parent of the cherry-picked commit. So the `cherry-pick` will create a new commit that expresses the difference between `v0.0.1` and the newly created and tagged commit that you made as its child, `v0.0.1b`. In other words, it will contain the fixes you want! So switch to `v0.0.2` (which requires a detached head), cherry-pick `v0.0.1b`, and don't forget to tag it to keep it alive; let's call this one `v0.0.2b`.

But we are now waving our hands. Do that for *all* you pre-existing releases. And then, don't forget to do it for `main` as well! You want it to have these fixes too, obviously. The only difference is that when you switch to `main` you are not detached, so you can just cherry-pick `v0.0.1b` and stop; the job is done. Now go on with life as usual.

Comment: I didn't expect this kind of answer at all, well elaborated and even refined my git knowledge. Huge kudos to you man, many many thanks !

Comment: You might like to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/